# GridView devexpress ESC to cancel editing

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can I get behaviour that while editing cell if user hits escape then editing should be canceled and previous value set ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

you need to override GridView.hideEditor method, please see [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B50274.aspx) for [more](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q274911.aspx) and here too. same can be [done](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q239627.aspx) by writing code also.