# GridView devexpress ENTER to go down

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

How can I achieve behaviour that when user hits enter after editing selection goes to the row below  (the same column) not the same row next column

thanks for help

Comment: You could also ask the two things in one question only --> [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204895/gridview-devexpress-esc-to-cancel-editing), and delete this question.

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with C# or Winforms.  The best place to get support for a 3rd party library is their support forum and/or technical help resources.  DevExpress has both afaik.

Comment: @HansPassant,tagging is correct as Devexpress have winForms and webForms controls(ASP.Net MVC too). SO is faster then Devexpress support forums, I seen them replying on SO also.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by [design](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q210145.aspx). But you can write your on implementation like,

```
GridView.KeyDown
{
  If(Key == Enter)
    Write code to go next line
 }
```

You can check [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=A252) also for more.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [keyboard navigation feature](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Accessibility/KeyboardSupport.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer but I had this problem too. , [As Devexpress Developers say](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ8369) You should handle the GridControl.ProcessGridKey event:

```
private void gridControl1_ProcessGridKey(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) {
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    (gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView).FocusedRowHandle++;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```